# What is this succulent plant with long, triangularly pointed leaves?

Tags: identification, succulents

Can anyone tell me what type of succulent this is?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That is Spear Head ([*Senecio kleiniiformis*](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/showimage/202135/)). Yours is beautiful, and looks like it gets just enough light!

[image]